# Vulkan abstraction similar to OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, vulkan

Because OpenGL is deprecating, I was wondering where to position myself to keep on learning graphics programming in the years to come on the same level of abstraction as OpenGL ? I don't want to go low-level with endless Vulkan / GPU settings, and would like to be in more or less the abstraction that OpenGL offers. What graphics library to choose ? Any good middleware that is suiting on top of Vulkan ? Or maybe I just have to learn Vulkan, lol.

Comment: Where did you get that OpenGL is deprecating? So far as I know it is not. Apart from that, there are projects like Vulkan Scene Graph. I have never used it, but their former product (OpenSceneGraph) did take away a lot of the OpenGL grunt you always have to do, so I assume it will do the same thing for Vulkan: https://vsg-dev.github.io/VulkanSceneGraph/

Comment: Ah, ok. I had the impression that it diverges from modern GPU architectures, and that's why e.g Apple stopped supporting it. Thank you for the suggestion, I will check it out!

Comment: @user1511956: Yes, modern hardware doesn't look like the OpenGL API. But this has been true basically since the mid-2000s. OpenGL is only "deprecated" on MacOS, and that's because Apple wants to push Metal.